# Draw nodes following a specific order on Networkx in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I didn't find any answer to the question I asked, maybe because I didn't use the correct words to express it, so I'll try asking her hoping someone can help me, thanks in advance.
I'm trying to draw graphs using the NetworkX library, version 2.5, with Python 3.9, running on Debian.
My graph consists in a node "s", a node "t", multiple nodes t_i , 1 <= i <= n , and multiple nodes v_j, 1 <= j <= m. There are edges connecting "s" and t_i nodes, between some t_i and v_j nodes, and between v_j and "t" nodes.

Is it possible to draw it like in the picture below (includes edges of course) ? I didn't find a way to order how the nodes are displayed...

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`multipartite_layout`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.multipartite_layout.html) for your desired positioning. You need to specify in a node attribute (see `level` below) to which group the node should belong and then retrieve a layout in the given levels. Adding edges will not change the position of the nodes, so I did not added them to the following minimal example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node("s", level=0)
G.add_node("t_1", level=1)
G.add_node("t_2", level=1)
G.add_node("v_1", level=2)
G.add_node("v_2", level=2)
G.add_node("v_3", level=2)
G.add_node("t", level=3)

pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G, subset_key="level")

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
pl.show()
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it perfectly answers my question. Do you know if there's a way to set a certain distanfe between layer i and layer i+1 ? I couldn't find this in the example given in the documentation (https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_multipartite_graph.html) , even when trying to change the code

Comment: You could directly modify the content of the return (`pos`). It is only a dictionary with the nodes as keys and two-dimensional arrays containing the x and y position. However, you can probably only change the relative distance between the layers. Otherwise you need to modify the figuresize (using matplotlib).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I checked it, pos contains a key value for each node (keys are 0 to n if there are n+1 nodes) , with pos[node] = (x,y) ; the coordinates of the node. The x values are equal for nodes in the same layer, so probably there's a way to change this value without editing  it for each node. I'll add a comment if I find more info

Comment: I would just like to mention that on `networkx==3.0` adding edges will indeed change the position of nodes in the levels