# Generate coordinates for a hierarchy Network graph when levels are given for each node

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, graph-visualization

Need to generate coordinates(only X axis) for a hierarchy Network graph **when levels (Y axis) are given for each node**. Here the X coordinated should be at optimal position in the given Y coordinate.

Currently I use *networkx* library with *graphviz_layout* in Python for this.

the code snippet used:

```
Q = nx.Graph()
Q.add_edges_from(arr_SrcTgt)
pos = graphviz_layout(Q,prog='dot')
nx.draw(Q,pos)
plt.show
```

output:

[image]

here bottom 4 nodes should be in top.

Therefore I decided to define levels(Y-axis) of each node and get the X coordinates by an algorithm.

Any ideas ? prefer python or excel :)
Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand what your are trying to do.  Suggest you provide a small sample ( 4 or 5 nodes ) with the expected output.

Comment: @ravenspoint I have edited my post. can you help?

Comment: Suggest you provide a small sample ( 4 or 5 nodes ) with the expected output

Comment: Suggest you take a look at the neato user manual https://graphviz.org/pdf/neatoguide.pdf.  You want the 'pos' node attribute.

Comment: thanks, but i want the graph as a hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried using neato?  What input did you use?  What did the result look like?  ( Still waiting for a small example )

Comment: How about the multipartite layout?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67599152/11339311

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I figured a way.

I used DiGraph instead of Graph in the same code.
Then All nodes were arranged as a hierarchy.

```
Q = nx.DiGraph()
```